# how to limit the embed can be viewed or split the embed into two pages

Tags: javascript, arrays, bots

when there are lot of songs in my queue, my bot crashes if I ran the queue command.
and it gives me this error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.description: Must be 2048 or fewer in length.
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.description: Must be 2048 or fewer in length
```

I asked someone, and he told me that the embed for the queue is too long.
I want my bot to limit the queue that can be seen or split the embed into two or more pages if the queue is too long.
can someone help me to do that?

and here's my code:

```js
async function handleVideo(video, message, voiceChannel, playlist = false) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
  const song = {
    id: video.id,
    title: Util.escapeMarkdown(video.title),
    url: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${video.id}`
  };
  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueConstruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: process.env.VOLUME,
      playing: true,
      loop: false
    };
    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);
    queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      queueConstruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueConstruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        `[ERROR] I could not join the voice channel, because: ${error}`
      );
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(
        `I could not join the voice channel, because: **\`${error}\`**`
      );
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    if (playlist) return;
    else
      return message.channel.send(
        `✅  **|**  **\`${song.title}\`** has been added to the queue! `
      );
  }
  return;
}
```